# Asp Classic Connection String 500 - Internal server error

Tags: sql, oracle, asp-classic

Hello I'm trying to connect to the oracle data source and seems like when i test the code its giving me an error. Also, I believe it might be my data source path is wrong. Is there way to check the data source path in oracle or any kind of way? Thanks

```html
    <!--INCLUDED FILE = reset_password.asp -->

    <%
    DIM strEmail
    strEmail = Request.Form("email")

    IF strEmail <> "" THEN
    %>
    <!--#INCLUDE VIRTUAL="/includes/connection.asp"-->
    <!-- ************SQL CONNECTION INSERT HERE*********************--> 
    <!-- *******
            Set objDB = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
            objDB.open "PROVIDER=MICROSOFT.JET.OLEDB.4.0;DATA SOURCE=c:\mydatabase.mdb"
    **** -->

    conn.
    <%

    DIM objDB
    objDB = "SELECT email_addr,medacist_password FROM medacist_user WHERE email_addr = '" & strEmail & "'"
    Set objDB = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    objDB.Open "PROVIDER=MICROSOFT.JET.OLEDB.4.0;DATA SOURCE= mmsg; Persist Security Info=True; User ID=mmsg; Password=langa;"

    IF objDB.EOF THEN
    Response.Write "That email address was not found in our database. Please click Back on your browser and enter the email address you registered with."
    ELSE
    DIM strPassword
    strPassword = objDB("medacist_password")

    DIM mail, objMail
    Set objMail = Server.CreateObject("CDONTS.NewMail") 
    objMail.From = "example@yahoo.com"
    objMail.Subject = "Your Password"
    objMail.To = strEmail
    objMail.Body = "Here is your login password: " & strEmail 
    objMail.Send

    'Set objMail to nothing to destory the mail object'
    Set objMail = nothing

    Response.Write "Your password has been sent to your email address."
    END IF

    ELSE
    Response.Write "Please click Back on your browser and enter the email address you registered with."
    END IF
```

Comment: did you check the line that causes this 500 error? I see a lot of issues in this code, even if you have a connection, it won't work: you need a connection and a recordset, now you treat the connection as a recordset. Read about ADO first: https://www.webwiz.co.uk/kb/asp-tutorials/connecting-to-an-access-database.htm (yes it's an Access db, but for Oracle only the connection string is different).

Answer (score 1):

MICROSOFT.JET.OLEDB.4.0 is the OLEDB provider for MS Access.  You'll need either an ODBC or an OLEDB connection string for Oracle.  See this page for options

http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/

After that you need a recordset object as kloarubeek suggests above. A very simple way to do this would be as follows.

```
    DIM objDB, rs, rssql
    Set objDB = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    objDB.Open "[your connection string goes here]"
    rssql = "SELECT email_addr,medacist_password FROM medacist_user WHERE email_addr = '" & strEmail & "'"
    Set rs = objDB.Execute(rsSQL)
```

Also I notice you are using CDONTS to send emails.  It's deprecated and you won't find it on current versions of IIS by default.  Look at CDOSYS instead

http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_send_email.asp

Finally, I recommend this page for anyone learning Classic ASP.  It explains how to get error messages which are more useful than the basic 500 internal server error page.

http://www.chestysoft.com/asp-error-messages.asp

Edit

An example of a password retrieval script using CDOSYS and a recordset.

NB The CDO configuration will depend on your smtp server.  Application("conn") means that my actual connection string is in a file called global.asa.  This page actually connects to a SQL Server db, but the code should work with Oracle

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>

<% 
If InStr(request.form("username"),"@") > 0 Then
Set objMail = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set iConfg = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
Set Flds = iConfg.Fields
With Flds
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "127.0.0.1"
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 587
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "youremailusername"
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "youremailpasword"
    .Update
End With
objMail.Configuration = iConfg
objMail.To = CStr(request.form("username"))
objMail.From = "you@yourdomain.com"
objMail.Subject = "Your login details"
objMail.TextBody = "Your login details are as follows " & vbcrlf & vbcrlf
set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.open Application("conn")

sql = "select ContactEmailAddress, ContactAffiliateUsername, ContactAffiliatePassword from Contacts where ContactEmailAddress ='" & request.form("username") & "'"



set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs.open sql,conn,3,1

If rs.bof And rs.eof Then
response.redirect("invalidemailpage.asp?invalidemail=2")

Else 

objMail.To = RS("ContactEmailAddress")
objMail.TextBody = objMail.TextBody & "Username = " & RS("ContactAffiliateUsername") & ", Password = " & RS("ContactAffiliatePassword") & vbcrlf


End If 

objMail.Send
Set objMail = Nothing

rs.close
set rs = nothing
conn.close
set conn = nothing 
response.redirect("login.asp?sentpassword=1")
Else
response.redirect("invalidemailpage.asp?invalidemail=1")
End If

%>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I changed the setting. But I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: DIM objDB, rssql
    Set objDB = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

    objDB.Open "Provider=MSDASQL.1;Password=langas;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=mmsg;Data Source=mmsg_web"
    rssql = "SELECT email_addr,medacist_password FROM medacist_user WHERE email_addr = '" & strEmail & "'"

Comment: Have you enabled detailed error messages as per my last suggestion. There are all sorts of things which may cause an error, that will help you pinpoint it.

Comment: Yes I did that, just saying error 500 and my file name confirm.asp. I add another asp file maybe this might helps. I updated the code please see answer 2.

Comment: Now i have this error:   arguments are of the wrong type are out of acceptable range. For this SQL

objDB = "SELECT email_addr,medacist_password FROM medacist_user WHERE email_addr = '" & strEmail & "'"
    Set objDB = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    objDB.Open "Provider=MSDASQL;Password=langas;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=mmsg;Data Source=mmsg_web"

Comment: I've edited my answer.  I've added a tried and tested send password script

Answer (score 0):

I update the code and try if work. And seems like result still the same error 500. I also add another asp file where user enter the email and click reset button direct to confirm.asp. What is wrong with my code.

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title> Reset Password</title>
</head>
<body>
 <STYLE type="text/css">
       BODY { 
    background: #B4D7EB url("https://www.medacist.com/images/pic_medacist_gradient.jpg");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
 background-attachment: scroll;

     }
 
</STYLE>
<div align="center">
 <table border="0" width="100" id="table1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
   <td valign="top">
   <table border="0" width="100%" id="table2" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr><td valign="top"><img border="0" src="https://www.medacist.com/images/pic_medacist_header.jpg"></td></tr>
    <tr><td valign="top">
     <table border="0" width="100%" id="table3" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
       <td valign="top" bgcolor="#BBD6E7"><a href="http://www.medacist.com/index.asp"><img border="0" src="https://www.medacist.com/images/pic_medacist_head_01.jpg"></a></td>
      
    
       <td valign="top" bgcolor="#BBD6E7"><img border="0" src="https://www.medacist.com/images/pic_medacist_nav_08.jpg"></td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td valign="top"><img border="0" src="https://www.medacist.com/images/pic_medacist_hrule_01.jpg"></td></tr>
    <tr><td valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
     <table border="0" width="100%" id="table4" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr><td valign="top">
       <table border="0" width="100%" id="table6" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        
        <tr><td valign="top"><img border="0" src="https://www.medacist.com/images/pic_medacist_main_slogan.jpg"></td></tr>
        <tr><td valign="top" >
     <center>        
 <table class="table1" width="100%" id="table8" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   </table>
   <h1>Forgot Your Password?</h1>
   <p>Please Enter Your Email. <br>
    
    <!-- *************************************************BUTTON CSS *********************************************************-->
    <style type="text/css">


                #submit {
        -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #efdcfb;
        -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #efdcfb;
        box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #efdcfb;
        background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #dfbdfa), color-stop(1, #bc80ea));
        background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #dfbdfa 5%, #bc80ea 100%);
        background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #dfbdfa 5%, #bc80ea 100%);
        background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #dfbdfa 5%, #bc80ea 100%);
        background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #dfbdfa 5%, #bc80ea 100%);
        background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #dfbdfa 5%, #bc80ea 100%);
        filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#dfbdfa', endColorstr='#bc80ea',GradientType=0);
        background-color:#dfbdfa;
        -moz-border-radius:5px;
        -webkit-border-radius:5px;
        border-radius:5px;
        border:1px solid #337bc4;
        display:inline-block;
        cursor:pointer;
        color:#ffffff;
        font-family:arial;
        font-size:14px;
        font-weight:bold;
        padding:4px 10px;
        text-decoration:none;
        text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #528ecc;
       }
       #submit:hover {
        background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #378de5), color-stop(1, #79bbff));
        background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #378de5 5%, #79bbff 100%);
        background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #378de5 5%, #79bbff 100%);
        background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #378de5 5%, #79bbff 100%);
        background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #378de5 5%, #79bbff 100%);
        background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #378de5 5%, #79bbff 100%);
        filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#378de5', endColorstr='#79bbff',GradientType=0);
        background-color:#378de5;
       }
       #submit:active {
        position:relative;
        top:1px;
       }
    </style>

   <form name="email" action="confirm.asp" method="post">
   <input type="email" name="email" size="30" required>
   <input id="submit" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Reset">
   </form>
  </td></tr>
  </table>
  </center>

    </td>
    <td valign="top" background="images/pic_medacist_vrule_sp2.jpg" width="1"><img border="0" src="https://www.medacist.com/images/pic_medacist_vrule_02.jpg" width="7" height="667"></td>
    </tr>
     </table>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td id="footer" valign="top">
     <style type="text/css">
      #footer{
       

       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
       border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
       background-image: url("../images/footer.gif");
       font-size: 11px;
       font-weight: bold;
       height: 35px;
       width: 650px;
       text-align: center;
       font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

      }

     
     </style>
     <span id="copyrightMessage">&copy; 1997 - 2015, Medacist Solutions Group, LLC. All rights reserved. U.S. Patent No. 6,842,736 entitled 'Drug Auditing Method and System'. 
     <br />   </span>
    </td></tr>
   </table>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td valign="top"><img border="0" src="https://www.medacist.com/images/0_ghost.gif" width="20" height="20"></td></tr>
 </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
    <%@ Language=VBScript %>
    <% Option Explicit %>
    <!--#include virtual=reset_password.asp"-->
    <html>
    <head><title>Edit User Information</title></head>
    <%
    Dim oConn, oRs
    Dim connectstr, sDSNDir, tablename
    Dim db_name, db_username, db_userpassword
    Dim dsn_name
     
    dsn_name = "MySQL_TEST.dsn"
    tablename = "medacist_user"
    db_username = "chang"
    db_userpassword = "PASSWORD123#"
     
    sDSNDir = Server.MapPath("/_dsn")
    connectstr = "filedsn=" & sDSNDir & "/" & dsn_name
     
    Set oConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    oConn.Open connectstr
     
    Dim EmailFrom
    Dim EmailTo
    Dim Subject
    Dim Message
     
    EmailFrom = "clu@medacist.com"
    EmailTo = Trim(Request.Form("email"))
    Subject = "Here is your Password"
    Message = "You're password is:" & objRS("Password" )


     
     
    Dim validationOK
    validationOK=true
    If (validationOK=false) Then Response.Redirect("index.html")
     
    Dim Body
    Body = Body & message
     
     
    Dim mail
    Set mail = Server.CreateObject("CDOSYS.NewMail") 
    mail.To = EmailTo
    mail.From = EmailFrom
    mail.Subject = Subject
    mail.Body = Body
    mail.Send 
     
     
   

    Dim objRS, bolFound, strEmail
    strEmail = Request.Form("email")
     
    If strEmail = "" Then
    oConn.Close
    Set oConn = Nothing
    Response.Write "<a href='reset_password.asp'>"
    Response.Write "You must enter a email address"
    Response.Write "</a>"
    Response.End
    End If
     
    Set objRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    objRS.Open "medacist_user", oConn, , , adCmdTable
    bolFound = False
     
    Do While Not (objRS.EOF OR bolFound)
    If (StrComp(objRS("email"), strEmail, vbTextCompare) = 0) Then
    BolFound = True
    Else
    objRS.MoveNext
    End If
    Loop
     
    If Not bolFound Then
    objRS.Close
    Set objRS = Nothing
    oConn.Close
    Set oConn = Nothing
    Response.Write "<a href='reset_password.asp'>"
    Response.Write "Invalid Email Address.<p>"
    Response.Write "</a>"
    Response.End
    End If



    Dim objRS, bolFound, strEmail
    strEmail = Request.Form("email")
     
    If strEmail = "" Then
    oConn.Close
    Set oConn = Nothing
    Response.Write "<a href='reset_password.asp'>"
    Response.Write "You must enter a email address"
    Response.Write "</a>"
    Response.End
    End If
     
    Set objRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    objRS.Open "medacist_user", oConn, , , adCmdTable
    bolFound = False
     
    Do While Not (objRS.EOF OR bolFound)
    If (StrComp(objRS("Email"), strEmail, vbTextCompare) = 0) Then
    BolFound = True
    Else
    objRS.MoveNext
    End If
    Loop
     
    If Not bolFound Then
    objRS.Close
    Set objRS = Nothing
    oConn.Close
    Set oConn = Nothing
    Response.Write "<a href='reset_password.asp'>"
    Response.Write "Invalid Email Address.<p>"
    Response.Write "</a>"
    Response.End
    End If
%>
    </body>
    </html>
```