# Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, ASP CLASSIC

Tags: html, sql, oracle, asp-classic

When I run my classic ASP it showing an error "Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another" Can anyone help me? Thanks

```html
    <%
    DIM strEmail
    strEmail = Request.Form("email")

    IF strEmail <> "" THEN
    %>
    
    <%

    DIM objDB, strSQL
    strSQL = "SELECT email_addr,medacist_password FROM medacist_user WHERE email_addr = '" & strEmail & "'"
    Set objDB = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    objDB.Open "Provider=MSDASQL;Data Source=mmsg_web; Persist Security Info=True;Password=langas;User ID=mmsg;"

    IF objDB.EOF THEN
    Response.Write "That email address was not found in our database. Please click Back on your browser and enter the email address you registered with."
    ELSE
    DIM strPassword
    strPassword = objDB("medacist_password")

    DIM mail, objMail
    Set objMail = Server.CreateObject("CDOSYS.NewMail") 
    objMail.From = "clu@medacist.com"
    objMail.Subject = "Your Password"
    objMail.To = strEmail
    objMail.Body = "Here is your login password: " & strEmail 
    objMail.Send

    'Set objMail to nothing to destory the mail object'
    Set objMail = nothing

    Response.Write "Your password has been sent to your email address."
    END IF

    ELSE
    Response.Write "Please click Back on your browser and enter the email address you registered with."
    END IF
    %>
```

Comment: You forgot to actually execute the query.

Comment: what u mean? Sorry im new to ASP

Comment: You put an SQL query in a string and open a database connection, but you never execute the query using the connection. If you look up some examples of how to execute a query you should see what's missing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asp Classic Connection String 500 - Internal server error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27748706/asp-classic-connection-string-500-internal-server-error)

Comment: @Guffa I added the execute code. objDB.Execute(strSQL) still showing error 500 - Internal server error

Comment: @Random: The `Execute` methods returns a recordset that you should assign to a variable. It's the recordset that has the data, not the connection object.

Comment: Here is what i Did

DIM objDB, rs, rssql
    Set objDB = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    objDB.Open "Provider=MSDASQL.1;Data Source=mmsg_web; Persist Security Info=True;Password=langas;User ID=mmsg"
    rssql = "SELECT email_addr, medacist_password FROM medacist_user WHERE email_addr = '" & strEmail & "'"
    Set rs = objDB.Execute(rsSQL)

Comment: i changed ADODB.Connection to ADODB.Recordset still having error. It's very difficult for me to debug since I'm running through test server not a local. No debug error shows beside 500 internal error message.